# Query on DAG triggers in cloud composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a simple requirement of scheduling and ETL job for bigquery using Google cloud composer. I have three staging tables(populated from files in a GCS bucket)  and one base table(loaded by joining the three staging tables). I have a framework written in an ETL tool which loads the data into bigquery staging table as soon as it's corresponding files arrives in the GCS bucket achieved using cloud function file arrival trigger. I have to set a dependency in the composer DAG which says execute my base table after successful completion of my three staging tables.
My dag will be roughly as below:

Task_stg_1: load stg table 1

Task_stg_2 : load stg table 2

Task_stg_3 : load stg table 3

Task_base : load base table

Task_base.setUpstream(Task_stg_1,Task_stg_2,Task_stg_3)

This is fine but the question is how to trigger my dag?

My ETL trigger point is file arrival event. In this case there are three staging files i.e. the staging tasks will trigger as on when their respective files arrive in trigger. Do I have to trigger the DAG multiple times for each staging file? In that case how will the airflow know which particular task to execute?

Comment: How do you plan to trigger the DAG?

Comment: That's exactly what I am struggling with. Is it possible to invoke the tasks inside a DAG using cloud function?   Does triggering DAG automatically starts the tasks within it ?   Will it wait for cloud function trigger of individual staging tasks?